# Code Contracts: How to express these conditions?

Tags: c#, code-contracts, specifications

I'm playing around with Code Contracts at the moment and I'm not completely sure whether the static methods of the Contract class are powerful enough to compete with mathematical notation of conditions.

Let's assume we got a simple factorial method

```
int Factorial(int n);
```

I would express the following conditions:

```
Precondition:
n >= 0

Postconditions:
Factorial(n) = 1, in case n = 0
Factorial(n) = n*(n-1)*...*1, in case n > 0
```

These conditions clearly specify the behavior of Factorial in a short and clean way. My question is, whether they can be expressed through Code Contracts.

The precondition is trivial:

```
Contract.Requires(n >= 0)
```

The conditional post condition might be expresses using

```
if(n==0)
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() == 1);
if(n > 0)
    ...
```

But I don't like the way I need the "if" statement here as it makes the plain list of pre- and postconditions harder to read. I hoped we would have something like

```
Contract.Ensures(...).InCase(...);
```

And last but not least, I do not have any idea how to express this, which is a common notation regarding math:

```
n*(n-1)*...*1
```

Guess I would need some kind of loop, but this would copy the whole implementation. Is there any smart way to express such notations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to the following:

```
Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<int>() == AlternativeFactorial(n));
```

where `AlternativeFactorial` is:

```
[Pure]
public static int AlternativeFactorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    if(n > 0)
    {
        //Alternative implementation.
    }
}
```

Of course anything you use in a contract should be side-effect free (pure).

Now as far as the factorial implementation, I cannot come up with a more compact "alternative" implementation than w0lf's. What you should consider though is changing the return value of your method from int to [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). Factorials can get very large very quickly. Also note that by adding a post-condition on the factorial value, you will pretty much double the time your method will take to return a result. This can be resolved by building `CodeContracts` only on the debug configuration.

Comment: and how would the `Factorial` method look like?

Comment: @w0lf You are right, I missed the last part of the question. I will update my answer.

Comment: Panos, it's not about compact alternatives. The wrong thing I see here is the duplication that appears between the method and the Code Contract, because both do the same thing. As we know, duplication is the root of many evils in software and should be avoided where possible.

Comment: @w0lf But this is not duplication. You need to test the results of your implementation of an algorithm with the results of another one that is accepted as correct. The important part is to have different implementations (or algorithms) that solve the same problem. If not then there is no point doing that. The solution using unit tests that you proposed is not an alternative to using CodeContracts. CodeContracts and unit-tests should both be used. They complement each other.

Comment: if you have an implementation that is accepted as correct, why not just use that?

Comment: *"The important part is to have different implementations (or algorithms) that solve the same problem."* - I'm pretty sure if I told that to my boss I'd be fired in the next secod.

Comment: @w0lf Out of context my phrase sounds too much. The OP is trying to find out if CodeContracts can "compete with mathematical notation of conditions". What would your boss say about that ;) Regarding your other question, sometimes people try to solve a problem despite that somebody else has already solved it. They might need a faster solution or one that conserves memory or they just want to do it themselves.

Comment: As I already stated, I think the Factorial sample is not the best one. Panos' statements are pretty obviously true if you think of more complex problems where alternative implementations are common.

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for are Unit Tests, not Code Contracts.

Tipically, checks like `if n=0, then f(n) = 1` and `if n=3, then f(n) = 6` are Test Cases that should be expressed as Unit Tests.

In your case, I think a suitable post condition would be something like "*The result is always >= 1*". And nothing more than that.

Assuming that your factorial class looks something like this:

```
public class Factorial
{
    public int Compute(int n)
    {
        if (n == 0)
            return 1;

        return n * Compute(n - 1);
    }
}
```

a suitable Unit Test written with the [NUnit Framework](http://www.nunit.org/) would be:

```
[TestFixture]
public class FactorialTests
{
    [TestCase(0, 1)]
    [TestCase(1, 1)]
    [TestCase(2, 2)]
    [TestCase(7, 5040)]
    [TestCase(10, 3628800)]
    public void Compute_ReturnsCorrectResult(int n, int expectedResult)
    {
        var sut = new Factorial();

        Assert.AreEqual(expectedResult, sut.Compute(n));
    }
}
```

**Update (after the comments)**

> Stating result >= 1 does not fully specify the algorithm.

I don't think the Code Contract's job is to specify the algorithm in detail. the algorithm is specified by the method.

If the Code Contract was a complex piece of logic like the method itself, then I guess we would need a Code Contract Contract to verify that the Code Contract performs the correct checks. This obviously leads to infinite recursion.

> I didn't expect `n*(n-1)*...*1` to be accepted by the compiler. But some generic range operator in a LINQ-flavoured way would surely be a gread addition, e.g. From(n).To(1).Product() or From(n).To(m).Sum()

If there was such a form of expressing factorials (and probably there is) you could certainly use it in your code, rather than the Code Contracts.

**Update 2**

Just for fun, I found a LINQ way of computing Factorials:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, n == 0 ? 1 : n).Aggregate((a, i) => a * i);
```

Comment: Don't think this is true. It is pretty common to specify outputs via logical conditions, e.g. when using Hoare rules. Stating result >= 1 does not fully specify the algorithm.

Comment: Maybe the same way Code Contracts supports quantifiers (e.g. forall) but you don't use them in implementations. I didn't expect n*(n-1)*...*1 to be accepted by the compiler. But some generic range operator in a LINQ-flavoured way would surely be a gread addition, e.g. From(n).To(1).Product() or From(n).To(m).Sum()

Comment: @mbue Please see the update to my answer. You raised some important points and I thought it was best to make them and the responses a part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But again I want to point out that specifying some general input/output conditions is common in math. Maybe the factorial method isn't a good example. Think of some metric algorithm that gives the distance between two entities. There may be alot of different implementations (manhattan-distance, euclidian distance,...) but some assumptions can always be made to the output: Triangle inequality, symmetry and non-negativity. But I understand that maybe I search for something else than "Code Contracts".

Comment: @mbue Actually I think that the Triangle Inequality is a great example for a Code Contract. If you had for instance a `Triangle` class where you had three properties for the length of each side, you could probably implement Triangle Inequality as an invariant (and have some validation logic in the properties).

Comment: @mbue Symmetry could also be such an example, and non-negativity is pretty close to what I suggested above (*"The result is always >= 1"*).

Comment: @mbue However, adding extremely complex conditions to the code can decrease the readability.